# ALL_COL_COMMENTS doesn't return all table objects given a certain user

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, data-dictionary

When logged in as the schema owner, I can run a query

```
select * from ALL_COL_COMMENTS WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'BLEH_%';
```

And I can see all the tables and columns that I expect.

However, if I login as a different user, the same query will return *some* of those tables, but not all of them.

**Why isn't `ALL_COL_COMMENTS` returning the same result set regardless of the user?**

The owner is the same for all of these tables (the schema owner). The other user can see a subset of those tables in `ALL_COL_COMMENTS`, but as far as it is concerned the other tables don't exist.

Comment: The `ALL_XXX` views only return objects to which the current user has access to, i.e. those for which the user has at least `select` privilege

Comment: Does the other user have any permissions on the tables it can't see comments for? If not it won't be able to see them in all_tables or all_tab_columns either...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a basic principle of security, which Oracle implements consistently - if you don't have any permissions on an object, as far as you're concerned, it doesn't exist. Divulging any information about it is a security breach under the principle of "a need to know basis", if you will.

The data dictionary is no different - if you don't have any permissions on the table, you shouldn't be able to query even structural information about it (e.g., as the data dictionary present). As far as you're concerned, there's no such table.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't supposed to return the same result set regardless of the user. The [documentation for `ALL_TAB_COMMENTS`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_2104.htm#REFRN20278) says:

> ALL_TAB_COMMENTS displays comments on the tables and views accessible to the current user.

Similar comments are shown on the other `ALL_*` tables, and they show the difference between the `USER_*`, `ALL_*` and `DBA_*` versions.

[The introduction to the static data dictionary views](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_1001.htm#i1572007) makes it clearer:

> Many data dictionary tables have three corresponding views:
>
> An `ALL_` view displays all the information accessible to the current
>   user, including information from the current user's schema as well as
>   information from objects in other schemas, if the current user has
>   access to those objects by way of grants of privileges or roles.
>
> A `DBA_` view displays all relevant information in the entire database.
>   `DBA_` views are intended only for administrators. They can be accessed
>   only by users with the `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY` privilege. This privilege
>   is assigned to the DBA role when the system is initially installed.
>
> A `USER_` view displays all the information from the schema of the
>   current user. No special privileges are required to query these views.

If your 'other' user can't see the tables in those views then it doesn't have any privileges on them. They can only see the ones they *do* have privileges on. This is intentional, for the reasons @Mureinik refers to.